# how to store a random answer to use later in python

Tags: python

I am new to coding and thought id give python a try.
This is what I am seeing:

```
 original = raw_input('Enter a word:') # how to store answer to this

 if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():

    print original.lower()
```

I want to know how to store any random word in response to "Enter a word". Say if someone typed "bob" or "Tingle" how would that word be stored to a variable? i.e variable = "answer"

Comment: `original` contains your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` will return what you typed,so the `original` variable will store the string you typed and its type is `string`.

For example:

```
>>> original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
Enter a word:value
>>> original
'value'
>>>
```

Comment: so if someone saw "enter a word" on a screen (without seeing the code)  and typed "bob", for example, "bob" would be stored as a variable? sorry if this is basic knowledge, i've only been learning for approx.: 10 hours

Comment: maybe I should have added I am having a crack at PygLatin.

Comment: @SteveYoung,as you said,if you input "bob",it will be the value of `original` variable.

Comment: @SteveYoung,if the solution can work for you,please mark it accpeted,then others can also know  this maybe work for them.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out... I think!

```
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original.lower()
first = original[0].lower()
print first
word = original.lower()
```

on screen would return:

Enter a word: Bob (hit enter)

bob

b

thanks for the help